# Maximum Value of Integrals: Calc 3

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The path $C$ is a line segment of length $39$ in the plane starting at $(1,4)$. For $f(x,y)=12x+5y$, consider $\int \nabla f \cdot dr$.

(a) Where should the other end of the line segment $C$ be placed to maximize the value of the integral?
At $x$=?, $y$=?

(b) What is the maximum value of the integral?

I am so confused on this. The prof went over four sections of textbook in 30 mins and then assigned 80 online homework questions plus a final exam all in less than one week. I am so overwhelmed and nervous, that any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Line Integrals. You should know a succinct formula for the line integral of $\nabla f$ from a point $P$ to a point $Q$.

Answer (score 1):

**(a) Hints**: In order to maximize the value of the integral, we will request that the path $C$ is parallel to $\nabla f$, i.e. $\nabla f = 12 \vec{i} + 5\vec{j}$. Hence, the path $C$ will have a parametric equation:
$$\vec {r} = (\vec{i} + 4\vec{j}) + t\vec{s}, \space \text{where} \space \vec{s} = 12 \vec{i} + 5\vec{j}, \space \text{so}$$

$$x=1+12t, \space y=4+5t.$$

Next, let the other endpoint of the path $C$ is at $(x_B, y_B)$. Since the length of the path $C$ is 39, we have:

$$\sqrt{(x_B - 1)^2 + (y_B-4)^2}=39$$

or

$$\sqrt{(12t)^2+(5t)^2}=39 \iff 13t=39 \iff \boxed{t=3}.$$

Thus the path $C$ ends at $B=(37, 19)$.

**(b) Hints**: By the Fundamental theorem of Line Integrals we have:

$$\int_C \nabla f \cdot \vec{r}= f(B) - f(A)= 539 - 32 = 507.$$

Comment: Thank you so much!